# Allow Groups to Expand/Collapse While Spreadsheet Is Password Protected. Even after closing the file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

While protecting formulas with standard code like this:

```
Sub TestMe

    dim myCell as range

    with Worksheets(1)
        For Each myCell In .Range("A1:R102").Cells
            If myCell.MergeArea.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                If myCell.HasFormula Then
                    myCell.Locked = True
                Else
                    myCell.Locked = False
                End If
            End If
        Next myCell
        
        .EnableOutlining = True
        .Protect "v", contents:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Everything seems to be ok, formulas are protected and the Excel grouping seems quite functionable. However, after closing the file and opening it again, if I try to press the <kbd>+</kbd> on the grouping, it does not want to work, giving this message:

> You cannot use this command on a protected sheet. To use this command, you must first unprotect the sheet (Review tab, Changes group, Unprotect Sheet button). You may be prompted for a password.

I may run the same code to unprotect it and then to protect it, **but** the idea is:

- to use the Excel file, without VBA
- with formula protection
- with functional grouping

I am using MS Office Professional Plus 2013 32 bits.

Is there a way to do it? Even manually? I have literally selected all checkboxes, yet no success:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open the excel file and under `Review` go to `Protect Sheet` and make sure to select:  `Select locked cells` `Select unlocked cells` and in order to expand/colapse the groupings for columns `Format columns` Same thing for rows with `Format Rows` . That should do it :) [Here](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/crVtbiRnj3) screen recording

Comment: Nope, `Format columns` and `Format Rows` still does not allow it. Have you tried it on your PC?

Comment: It does work, now, bear in mind that you will only be able to click the + or - sign, not create a new grouping once the sheet is protected. Another thing you can do is select ```Scenarios``` in the protection. You can define this scenarios to prevent specific cases

Comment: I am perfect with clicking the + or - signs only and having the formulas locked. But somehow, it does not work for me, after I close and reopen the excel file.

Comment: Have you try it on a brand new workbook? I wonder if you have some extra layers of protection on the workbook such as restriction to read-only that are preventing this to work. I tried it on both ```.xlsx``` and ```.xls``` MS Excel 97-2003 and is still work

Comment: Just tried on a brand new worksheet. Does not work. Can you upload `xlsx` sheet somewhere, both with locked cells and data grouping?

Comment: I have add the file and a screen recording to the posted answered, let me know if that helps @Vityata

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. I have downloaded the file. The grouping does not work for me, I get the MessageBox with ... `You cannot use this command on a protected sheet...`

Comment: Can you share a file with me? See if the other way around the issue persists or not, and we can narrow down the issue to the MS Excel version or some other user config

Comment: Enjoy - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V0ww6NMrmjwB0m9r6mcD7HMtwXs989BN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Interesting, I cannot expand them either ... However I was able to do it replicating the issue on that same workbook on a separate sheet .. I checked if the fact of being binary format ```.xlb``` affected and it does not ... I would try to restore default user configurations see if that makes it, otherwise I'm sorry I run out of ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your example works is because you are setting the `UserInterfaceOnly` flag when protecting the worksheet.

Unfortunately the `UserInterfaceOnly` flag does not retain state after the workbook is closed. It simply gets reset. That means that you need to unprotect the worksheet and protect it back while applying the `UserInterfaceOnly` flag again. You can use the `Workbook_Open` event to unprotect/protect back with the flag set.

However, you mentioned that you do not want to use VBA. If you don't mind that users can change the formatting then you should use the advice given to you by @IñigoS in his answer. Just replace:

```
.Protect "v", Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

with:

```
.Protect "v", Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True
```

and if you want both rows and columns then:

```
.Protect "v", Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
```

**EDIT**

The above does not work on Office 2013 Professional Plus (tested). You are stuck with using VBA to unprotect the worksheet and then protected back with the `UserInterfaceOnly` flag set to `True` most likely in the `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: So, no way without VBA? The `Workbook_Open` event is not a solution, it is VBA code.

Comment: @Vityata Yes, you can skip the VBA by using the advice given by @IñigoS. But this comes with the downside of allowing people to format column/row widths. I don't see it as a problem. The actual formatting (e.g. font, color) won't be affected unless you decide to use the ```AllowFormattingCells``` flag.

Comment: Have you managed to receive both grouping and formula protection? Because I tried it and I could not get it. At first it worked, then after closing and opening again it was not working.

Comment: @Vityata Yes, formulas are protected and grouping works fine even after re-opening the workbook.

Comment: I am with MS Office Professional Plus 2013, running literally this `.Protect "v", Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True` and I cannot press on the expanding, after closing the file. Are you really sure it works?

Comment: @Vityata I am running on Office 365 ProPlus Version 2002 (Build 12527.21416). It works on my version. I guess it doesn't work because this behaviour is not available in your older version.

Comment: @Vityata I managed to get an Office Professional Plus 2013 installed. None of the parameters available in the ```Protect``` method provide you with the desired functionality, except the ```UserInterfaceOnly``` which gets reset when you close the workbook. So, the advice given by @IñigoS works on newer versions only. You are stuck with running VBA on the ```Workbook_Open``` event where you can unprotect and then protect back using the ```UserInterfaceOnly``` flag. Altough his advice is not fixing your problem consider upvoting his response as he did not know you are using Office 2013

Comment: I have to use `Workbook_Open` I will consider not using the data groups at all. But I have a feeling you are right, I tried to fight another 30 minutes today with no success. Still, will wait for a couple of more days, somehow there could be someone, knowing a magic solution...

Comment: According to documentation, it's really not possible to save UserInterfaceOnly=True: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect
"If you apply this method with the UserInterfaceOnly argument set to true and then save the workbook, the entire worksheet (not just the interface) will be fully protected when you reopen the workbook. To re-enable the user interface protection after the workbook is opened, you must again apply this method with UserInterfaceOnly set to true."

Comment: I guess Workbook_Open would be the a good way, this would be enough:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining = True
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="pwd", userInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
To prevent other users from seeing the password in VBA, you could protect the VBA project. But users would need to enable macros for it to work.